# Layout and functionality of matDatepicker does not work correctly

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I just can’t figure out what I forgot to connect. But in the end I have a datepicker that is impossible to use
[image]

"@angular/material": "^9.2.3"

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in style.css